# Algoritmo ShellSort C++

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Boa tarde pessoal!
Alguem pode me ajudar, me explicando este codigo em c++:

```
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < stdio.h>
#include < ctime>

void shellSort(int numbers[], int array_size);


int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){

//seed random number generator
srand((unsigned)time(0)); //Descomente essa linha caso voce queira que o programa gere os numeros aleatorios.

int NUM_ITEMS = 5;
int numbers[5];
int i;

//Descomente o trecho abaixo caso voce queira que o programa gere os numeros aleatorios.
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
numbers[i] = rand();


//numbers[100] = {12,2,6,9,5,7,16,55,32,15}; //Comente esse trecho, caso voce descomente o trecho de codigo acima.

shellSort(numbers, NUM_ITEMS);

printf("Numeros em ordem crescente:\n");
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
printf("%i\n", numbers[i]);

return 0;
}


void shellSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{
int i, j, increment, temp;

increment = 3;
while (increment > 0)
{
for (i=0; i < array_size; i++)
{
j = i;
temp = numbers[i];
while ((j >= increment) && (numbers[j-increment] > temp))
{
numbers[j] = numbers[j - increment];
j = j - increment;
}
numbers[j] = temp;
}
if (increment/2 != 0)
increment = increment/2;
else if (increment == 1)
increment = 0;
else
increment = 1;
}
}
```

Estou com dificuldade para entender o funcionamento do algoritmo Shell Sort.

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort

Comment: Qual a dificuldade está encontrando, onde exatamente está a dificuldade?

Comment: Só como aparte isso é código C e não C++, algo que pode até ver pelo link que o @MagicHat colocou. Tente explicar exatamente o que não percebe no código. A indentanção também ajuda

Comment: @Isac É código C++ mesmo, basta observar que ele adicionou a biblioteca 'ctime' que no C seria 'time.h' e que por sua vez não funciona no C só no C++, mais achei estranho ele usar 'printf'...

Comment: @Khyser Essa biblioteca existe em C normal, basta trocar o include para `<time.h>` . Tudo o resto é C, nem `cout`, nem `vector`, so puro C

Comment: @Isac Sim, eu sei, só queria dizer que era código C++ pela biblioteca que ele usou :p